# how to close the tabbar group in emacs

Tags: emacs, tabbar

I use tabbar in emacs.

I can use [C-x k] to kill the buffer.

But how can i kill the group?

[image]

Comment: I think the answer will vary depending upon how your group is defined, because it may be necessary to loop through the buffer list and search for buffers matching however your group was defined.  Therefore, unless I'm mistaken, posting your buffer group definition would be needed to answer your question.  My group, for example, is not only by certain buffer criteria, but by frame as well -- so the group is different depending upon which frame I am on -- however, most people don't use such a grouping structure.

Comment: If you have altered / customized the `tabbar-buffer-list-function`, then we need that too.  So, at the very least, we need the `tabbar-buffer-groups-function` and then perhaps the `tabbar-buffer-list-function` as well.